# How to change disk decryption screen resolution (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: encryption, display-resolution

The password entry screen for decrypting the drive is displayed at a resolution of 3840x2160. The resolution of my monitor is 1920x1080. How to set this decryption screen resolution? Now it is hardly readable.

The drive was encrypted during the Ubuntu installation.

The GRUB screen and login to the system is in the desired resolution.